# How to print P6Spy log statements to the Tomcat console

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, p6spy

I've integrated `P6Spy` into my `Netbeans` project, and the `SQL` log statements are being printed to the `spy.log` file in the `Tomcat` home directory. How do I get the `SQL`log statements to be printed to my `Tomcat` console?

Context:

- server is `Tomcat` 8
- database is `MySql`
- using `Hibernate` to query the database

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the default file logger.  Assuming that you are using P6Spy 2.X, you can switch to an alternate logger as described in the [documentation](http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/configandusage.html).

You can either use the StdoutLogger logger which will write to the console (but not the file) or you can switch to the Slf4JLogger logger for even more control over the log output.  I would generally recommend the Slf4JLogger since it allows for integration with your application's existing logging.

Answer (score 0):

P6spy is really great for logging your SQL statements. If you want to print out the statements on the console just enable in spy.properties the next line:

```
appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger
```

[image: SQL statements on the Console]